# Find the Kth smallest number whose digits have a sum of 10

Tags: algorithm, recursion, while-loop, sum, digits

**Looking for alternative algorithms**

**Below are the ones l have made but are being flagged as incorrect by the Online Judge on a coding website.**

After declaring variable of int data type k, l received an input
from the console using cin().
Since the constraints of the question read that the possible number(s) is/are
between 1 and 20000, l first off opened a for loop using these conditions.
At every iteration of i (one after the other), the number is tested  whether its digits sum up
to 10 and if they do, whether its the kth number whose digits are of sum 10.

To find the sum of digits, l used either a recursive function or an iterative method using a while loop.
Hence the two snippets of codes. In both methods, the sum is calculated by finding the digits first using modular % operator and division operator /. The sum is figured out and then further tested if its equal to 10 and if Yes, it is also tested if its the K th element by means of keeping count of all previous similar elements. After all conditions are satisfied, only then is the value i outputted using cout().

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

//recursion to get sum of digits.

*int sum(int d)

{

 return d==0?0:d%10+sum(d/10);

}*

int main()

{
  
  //ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

  //cin.tie(NULL);

   int t;

   cin>>t;

   while(t-- >0)

   {

    int k;

    cin>>k;

    for(int i=0;i<20000;i++)

    {

     int total=sum(i);

      if(total==10)

     {

      --k;

      if(k==0)

      cout<<i<<"\n";

      }

     }

  }

   return 0;

}
```

**Second one, l used iterations(while loop) to deduce sum of digits**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
  
  //ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

  //cin.tie(NULL);

   int t;

   cin>>t;

   while(t-- >0)

   {

    int k;

    cin>>k;

    for(int i=0;i<20000;i++)

{

     int sum=0,d=i;

     *while(d!=0)

       {

          sum+=d%10;

           d/=10;

       }*


     if(sum==10)

       {

         --k;

          if(k==0)

          cout<<i<<"\n";

        }
    }

 }

return 0;

}
```

> So l need alternative algorithms of better efficiency. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get wrong answers (for which `k` value?), or is it a problem of efficiency (too slow)?

Comment: I got the correct values in both case of implementations. But im working with an online judge, this code runs with no Time Limited Error on other compilers. Just that maybe the algorithms im using are considered incorrect(By the Online Judge)

Comment: Note that you shoulg get out of the loops (or return) once you get and print the correct answer.

Comment: Okay noted .Let me edit my code for another situation that might be affected by coming out of the loop(return). There is not only 1 test case but multiple test cases. The variable for these is t.

Comment: You could provide a link to the problem.

Comment: Thats the full problem now. I had just missed the test cases.

Comment: It a number is not found, you don't print anything. Again, you should provide a link to the problem.

Comment: https://mycode.prepbytes.com/contest/MARATHONAPRIL21/problems/HELPCLAY

Comment: Thats the link to the problem.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Note that 20000 limitation is for the input `K`, not for the number to be found...

Comment: Sorry but im facing an issue here, Your previous response is more than one line long and so its format is long and has(.....) dots at the end. But l cant seem to read more after the word found....any idea how to solve this. Tried to move discussion to chat, but l dont have enough reputation here. I do need assistance though. Any suggestions

Comment: But yes, l have notice that 20000 is a limit for k and not for the number...

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, it was a simple fix thanks to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231143/discussion-between-secondtonone-and-damien).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue of your code is that you limit the search for values less than 20000.

In order to improve the efficiency, I added two tricks

- I avoid to perform the same calculation several times, by memorizing the previous results
- According to the value of the sum of the digits, I adjust the value of the increment

On my PC, it takes 0.15s to calculate the maximum value (for `k = 20000`).

**Additional explanations**

In the code, the `i` variable corresponds to the *candidates*, i.e. the values that we test whether the sum of digits is equal to 10 or not.

`num` corresponds the the index of found solutions. A solution corresponds to a number, the sum of digits of which is equal to 10. `mem[num] = i` means that `i` is the `num^th` solution. `k` has the same meaning as in OP's code: we want to find the `k^th` number such that sum of digits = 10.

The two lines `int kmax = 1; mem[1] = 19;` use the fact that `19` is the first valid solution. This is needed to initialise the management of the `mem` vector, which memorizes all found solutions.

The tricks used to accelerate the process are the following:

- if the sum of current number `i` is equal to 10, then we know that there is no other solution between `i` and `i+8`. For example, after 27, the next solution is equal to 36. So we can do `i += 9` instead of simply `i++`.
- if the sum is higher than 10, then we will not find solution by simply increasing the first digit. For example, if `i = 85`, we can go directly to `90`, i.e. nulling the least digit. This is performed with `i += (10 - i%10);`
- if the sum is less than 10, e.g. 5, then you can directly add 5 instead of 1. This is performed with `i += (10 - total);`

In practice, it could be possible to go further. For example, if `i = 99000`, then we could  directly add 1000 instead of 10. I did not go so far, as the obtained code seems over-skill already a little bit (0.15s instead of 1s).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int sum(int d) {
    int ans = 0;
    while(d) {
        ans += d%10;
        d /= 10;
    }
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    std::vector<int> mem(20001, 0);
    int kmax = 1;
    mem[1] = 19;
    while(t-- >0) {
        int i, k;
        std::cin >> k;
        int num = 1;
        if (k > kmax) {
            i = mem[kmax];
            num = kmax;
            while(true) {
                int total = sum(i);
                if(total == 10) {
                    mem[num] = i;
                    if (num == k) break;
                    num++;
                    i += 9;
                } else {
                    if (total > 10) {
                        i += (10 - i%10);
                    } else {
                        i += (10 - total);
                    }
                }
            }
            kmax = k;
        }
        std::cout << mem[k] <<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It takes about 3 to 5 seconds on my PC. The unoptimized code takes  about 8 to 10 seconds. Its a good feeling when code runs fast.

Comment: Which compiler option did you use? I use `O3`. Did you check it on the on line site?

Comment: If you feel like l asked the question properly, please do upvote my responses. Your responses are very useful. If there is anything else you would like to inform me. Do not hesitate to tell. I will ask questions where l feel l don't quite understand.

Comment: What do you mean by *my responses*? You question post? Your answer?

Comment: Codeblocks-Offline. Onlinw it takes between 2 to 4 seconds when not using an interactive console. i.e preset text input.

Comment: The time limit on the site is 1s. So it is not fast enough?

Comment: My question post and the answer post(though yours has better efficiency).

Comment: On the site, yours runs for 0.01s.Its fast enough.

Comment: Mine runs 4 to 5 times slower

Comment: Could you explain what the i, num and k really mean?

Comment: `num` corresponding the the index of found solutions. A solution corresponds to a number, the sum of digits of which is equal to 10. `mem[num] = i` means that `i` is the num^th solution. `k` has the same meaning as in your code: we want to find the k^th number such that sum of digits = 10.

Comment: I understand your algorithm now, which begs the question....What's a situation where the variable total != 10, and where we might actually use the code defined in the else loop. To my understanding, the value of i since initialized as 19 or a number that's also a solution?  Do we really "need" the else part? Genuinely asking. Correct me if my deductions are incorrect.

Comment: And how does removing that part affect code execution?

Comment: I added an answer with digit dp to handle larger input. Great answer, though, but I don't understand the main `if else` blocks in the `while(true)` loop. Could you please add some words to describe it?

Comment: I tried to add some explanations. @גלעדברקן

Comment: Thanks, great ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the obligatory digit dynamic-program for completeness. This one will let you find the 200,000th (never mind 20,000th) almost immediately with binary search.

JavaScript code:

```js
function g(digits, i, sum, bound, memo){
  const key = String([i, sum, bound]);

  if (memo.hasOwnProperty(key))
    return memo[key];
    
  if (sum == 0)
    return memo[key] = 1;
    
  if (i == 0)
    return sum <= (bound ? digits[0] : 9);

  let result = 0;
  
  const k = bound ? digits[i] : 9;

  for (let d=0; d<=k && d<=sum; d++){
    const _bound = digits[i] == d ? bound : 0;
    result += g(digits, i-1, sum-d, _bound, memo);
  }
  
  return result;
}


function f(n, sum){
  const digits = [];
  
  while(n){
    digits.push(n % 10);
    n = Math.floor(n/10);
  }
  
  return g(digits, digits.length-1, sum, 1, {});
}

console.log(f(320002210, 10));

console.log(f(320002209, 10));
```

Comment: It looks quite efficient. I guess some explanations would be useful, at least for persons like me who don't know javascript !=) I understand that this code determines rapidly the number of solutions less than a given number. Then, from that, by using a binary search (not shown ?!), it would be fast to determine the `k^th` solution. I may be wrong completely ...

Comment: @Damien yes, it determines the number of solutions less than or equal to a given number, and the binary search is not included.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in a "recursive" way.

If a given number starts with the digit d, then the digits that follow must have the sum 10-d. As the numbers do not exceed 20000, they have at most 5 digits and the first is one of 0, 1.

A simple solution is to use four nested loops. Then you check if the last digit is legal.

```
n= 0
for d4= 0 to 1
    for d3= 0 to min(9, d-d4)
        for d2= 0 to min(9, d-d4-d3)
            for d1= 0 to min(9, d-d4-d3-d2)
                d0= 0 d-d4-d3-d2-d1
                if 0 <= d0 and d0 <= 9:
                    n+= 1
                    if n == k stop
```

Some micro-optimizations are possible. Using this method, I find 502 distinct solutions.

Comment: How do I implement the above code into my solution in that case?

Comment: @WSams; isn't the pseudocode easy enough ?

Comment: Lemmi take a closer look and try myself once more. Im still trying to comprehend the pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

I had made a misinterpretation of the constraints but finally here is the solution.
the 1<=K<=2*10^4 constraint was for the variable K, the value of the number X was a positive integer hence I initialised x=1. I applied a break statement(so as to take execution out of it when the number is found and printed) inside the infinite loop i.e
while(1).

Topics included are:
Recursion, Iterations, if statements, Loop control statements.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
  //write your code here

  //ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

 // cin.tie(NULL);

  int t;

  cin>>t;

  while(t>0)

  {

    int k;

    cin>>k;

    int x=1;

    while(1)

    {

     int sum=0;

     int d=x;

     while(d!=0)

     {

     sum+=d%10;

      d/=10;

     }

      if(sum==10)

      k--;

      if(k==0)

      {

      cout<<x<<"\n";

      break;

      }

      x++;

    }

    t--;

    }

     return 0;

     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting. Good to know how its done.